# Как найти расстояние между пикселями на изображении python

Tags: python, изображения, numpy

Посчитайте расстояние между черными пикселями на картинке.
Ответ округлите до пяти знаков после точки.
Если дробной части нет, дробная часть отбрасывается.
[image: Картинка]

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import math
 
im=Image.open("index.png").convert("RGB")
 
npimage=np.array(im)

p1, p2 = np.argwhere((npimage == [0, 0, 0]).all(axis=2))
l = abs(complex(*p1) - complex(*p2))
 
print(round(l, 5))
```

Comment: да, наверно и на квадрате Малевича есть белые пятна, которые не видно)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, в исходнике видно https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iH4H.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас трёхканальное изображение M x N x 3 (как в вашем коде), то можно сделать так:

```
p1, p2 = np.argwhere((npimage == [0, 0, 0]).all(axis=2))
l = abs(complex(*p1) - complex(*p2))
```

Если вы будете открывать изображение сразу в оттенках серого:

```
im=Image.open("index.png").convert("L")
```

Или конвертируете уже открытое трёхканальное изображение:

```
im = im.convert("L")
```

То решение будет такое:

```
p1, p2 = np.argwhere(npimage == 0)
l = abs(complex(*p1) - complex(*p2))
```

Если у вас изображение с одним каналом и размерностью M x N x 1, то просто убирите последнюю размерность:

```
p1, p2 = np.argwhere(npimage[:,:,0] == 0)
l = abs(complex(*p1) - complex(*p2))
```

Comment: Можно пожалуйста полный код...

Comment: @Masha, это вполне себе полный код. А где ваш хоть какой-то код?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/E1GiBuC7

Comment: @Masha, добавьте его в вопрос

Comment: @Masha, я добавил в ответ различных вариантов

Comment: Так,а как мне ваши варианты использовать? Я просто новичок

Comment: @Masha, я обновил ответ

Comment: `abs(complex(*p1) - complex(*p2))` - это настолько круто, что я теперь буду использовать это везде где возможно

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев,Извините, попробовав сдать координаты из вашего решения я получил не правильный ответ...

Comment: @Masha, ну с вашей картинкой у меня получились точки `[46,  1]` и `[120,  67]`. Расстояние там `99.15644204992432`. Что не так? Какой правильный ответ?

Comment: Дело в том что правильного ответа я не знаю...

Comment: @Masha, ну слушайте, если вы правильно воспользовались написанным мною кодом, то проблем быть не должно.  Добавьте в вопрос оригинальное условие задания и итоговый ваш код.

Comment: @Masha, ну вы округлили ответ?

Comment: Да, я округлял, но все равно не верно

Comment: @Masha, а что насчëт случая, когда дробной части нет?

Comment: Таких случаев не встречается, я отправлял только ответы с дробной частью

Comment: Т.е. вы знаете ВСЕ тестовые картинки? Тогда знаете ли вы, на каких именно картинках не проходит?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124400/discussion-between---and-masha).

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев. понял в чем ошибка, написал в чате